# how to fix Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, rotation, android-gps

i.m new in android.
its app to direction of qibla. actually i have 3 classes: main, GPS servive, and RoseGPS (to rotate needle).from that main activity class i want to call a functions of other class. error appear when i add RoseGPS. help me to fix it.

MainActivity

```
public class GPSMainActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener{
//public class GPSMainActivity extends Activity{
TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4;
AppService appService;
Context context;
double latMasjid, lonMasjid;
public  static double degree;
private RelativeLayout direcCantainer;
SensorManager sensorManager;
static final int sensor=SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION;
private RoseGPS rose;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsmain);
    textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDegree);
    textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
    textView4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLong);
    appService=new AppService(GPSMainActivity.this);

    Location gpsLocation = appService.getLocation();
    if (gpsLocation != null) {
        latMasjid=gpsLocation.getLatitude();
        lonMasjid = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
        String resultLat = "Latitude: " + gpsLocation.getLatitude() +
                " Longitude: " + gpsLocation.getLongitude();
        textView4.setText(resultLat);
    } else {
        textView3.setText("gagal");
    }
    degree=bearing(latMasjid,lonMasjid,21.42243,39.82624);
    textView2.setText(String.format("%.2f", degree)+(char)0x00B0);

    direcCantainer=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.cantainer_layout);
    rose = new RoseGPS(context);
    direcCantainer.addView(rose);
    rose.invalidate();
    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(context.SENSOR_SERVICE);       
}  

protected double bearing(double startLat, double startLng, double endLat, double endLng){
    double longitude1 = startLng;
    double longitude2 = endLng;
    double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(startLat);
    double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(endLat);
    double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2 - longitude1);
    double y= Math.sin(longDiff)* Math.cos(latitude2);
    double x= Math.cos(latitude1)* Math.sin(latitude2)- Math.sin(latitude1)* Math.cos(latitude2)* Math.cos(longDiff);

    return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
}

public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values){
    if(sensor != GPSMainActivity.sensor)
        return;
    int orientation = (int)values[0];
    rose.setDirections(orientation, orientation);
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy){

}
```

RoseGPS

```
public class RoseGPS extends View{

GPSMainActivity fragment1GPSMainActivity = new GPSMainActivity();

private float directionNorth=0;
private float directionQibla=0;
private TextView bearingNorth, bearingQibla;
private String bearingNorthString, bearingQiblaString;
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
private Bitmap compassBackground, compassNeedle;
private Matrix rotateNeedle=new Matrix();
private int width=240;
private int height=240;
private float centre_x=width*0.5f;
private float centre_y=height*0.5f;

public RoseGPS(Context context){
    super(context);
    initCompassView();
}

public RoseGPS(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    initCompassView();
}

public RoseGPS(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    initCompassView();
}

public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    setMeasuredDimension(width,height);
}

private void initCompassView(){
compassNeedle=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.panah_36);
compassBackground=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kompas_72);
width=compassBackground.getWidth()*2;
height=compassBackground.getHeight()*2;

centre_x=width*0.5f;
centre_y=height*0.5f;
rotateNeedle.postTranslate(centre_x - compassNeedle.getWidth()/2, centre_y - compassNeedle.getHeight()/2);
invalidate();
}

public void setConstants(TextView bearingNorth, CharSequence bearingNorthString, TextView bearingQibla, CharSequence bearingQiblaString){
    this.bearingNorth=bearingNorth;
    this.bearingNorthString=bearingNorthString.toString();
    this.bearingQibla=bearingQibla;
    this.bearingQiblaString=bearingQiblaString.toString();
}

public void setDirections(float directionsNorth, float directionsQibla){
    this.directionNorth=directionsNorth;
    this.directionQibla=directionsQibla;
    rotateNeedle=new Matrix();
    float degree=(float) GPSMainActivity.degree;

    rotateNeedle.postRotate(degree, compassNeedle.getWidth()/2, compassNeedle.getHeight()/2);
    rotateNeedle.postTranslate(centre_x - compassNeedle.getWidth()/2, centre_y - compassNeedle.getHeight()/2);
    invalidate();
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    bearingNorth.setText(bearingNorthString.replace("(1)", df.format(directionNorth)));
    bearingQibla.setText(bearingQiblaString.replace("(+/-)", directionQibla>=0 ? "+" : "-").replace("(2)", df.format(Math.abs(directionQibla))).replace("(3)", df.format(directionNorth+directionQibla)));

    Paint p=new Paint();
    canvas.rotate(-directionNorth, centre_x, centre_y);
    canvas.drawBitmap(compassBackground, compassBackground.getWidth()/2, compassBackground.getHeight()/2, p);
    canvas.drawBitmap(compassNeedle, rotateNeedle, p);
}
```

my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cantainer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDegree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/idDegree"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/idLat" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/idLon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my Logcat

```
 11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): Process: com.gpsaja, PID: 2177
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gpsaja/com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:352)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3448)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.gpsaja.RoseGPS.<init>(RoseGPS.java:33)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity.onCreate(GPSMainActivity.java:64)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-24 02:04:51.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2177):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Obviously you can't do this `new GPSMainActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

```
rose = new RoseGPS(context);
```

`context` is `null`. Remove the `context` field from your code. Then, change this line to:

```
rose = new RoseGPS(this);
```

as `Activity` inherits from `Context`, and you need to create widgets for an activity using the activity as the `Context` anyway.